# How to get Three Letter Acronym of Time Zone for ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, time

I'm trying to get the format of `EDT` for my `ZonedDateTime`'s formatter.

According to the fomatter spec, this should be to use the `z` option, but this doesn't appear to work instead producing the output of `GMT+4`.

I'm on Ubuntu, and I'm not sure if this is platform specific or not.

Here is my code:

```
/**
     * The date time formatter for snapshot dates.
     */
    public static final DateTimeFormatter SNAPSHOT_FORMAT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ssz")
            .toFormatter();
```

& What is produces:

```
14-08-2019_18:45:52GMT-04:00
```

How can I turn the `GMT-4` to `EDT`?

[image: Page]

**EDIT 0:** Where I get the `ZonedDateTime` from :

```
ZonedDateTime.now();
```

Comment: I'd warn you about using the letter form of the timezone here.  GMT -4 is unambiguous, whereas the letter form can be *extremely* ambiguous.

Comment: @Makoto Interesting, I would think that EDT would be distinct. Perhaps I can append the EDT after the `z` then?

Comment: On my system, the "z" prints out "PDT", which is correct for my time zone.  Dunno what's up with your system.  What version of Java, what's your OS?  Check those for updates too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because the `ZoneId` in your `ZonedDateTime` doesn't have that information.

*Showcase*

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ssz");

ZonedDateTime zdtEastern = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
ZonedDateTime zdtMinus4 = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT-04:00"));

System.out.println(zdtEastern.format(fmt)); // Prints: 14-08-2019_19:40:36EDT
System.out.println(zdtMinus4.format(fmt));  // Prints: 14-08-2019_19:40:36GMT-04:00
```

You need to **fix the `ZoneId` value of the `ZonedDateTime`**. Since we don't know where/how you got the value, we can't help with that.

*Unrelated:* Note how you don't need to use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` if you just use a pattern.

Comment: This is interesting, I just called `ZonedDateTime.now()`, I would have assumed that it knows the time zone.

Comment: @SarahSzabo It only knows the time zone if Java can obtain it from the OS. If the OS only supply an offset, then Java cannot invent the zone. Could be the OS is misconfigured. Try printing `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to see what Java sees, e.g. does it print `America/New_York` or `GMT-04:00`?

Comment: Yep, it prints `America/New_York`

Comment: @SarahSzabo So your Java knows the real time zone. I guess your `ZonedDateTime` value was obtained through some means other than by calling `now()`.

Comment: For me `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d LLL, YYYY hh:mm a z"))` results in `14 Oct, 2021 05:33 AM GMT-04:00`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here and is confused as to why the required Zone Id is present, but still it's giving the offset from GMT, **it could be the locale**:

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
  .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d LLL, YYYY hh:mm a z"))
```

Results in `14 Oct, 2021 05:33 AM GMT-04:00` because my system default locale is UK. To get the three letter acronym, explicitly set the US locale:

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
  .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d LLL, YYYY hh:mm a z").withLocale(Locale.US))
```

This will give `14 Oct, 2021 05:33 AM EDT` which is what OP is looking for.